# How to evaluate $\int \frac{dx}{(1-x)\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ without a trig substitution/parts?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, alternative-proof

I'd like to find

$$\int \frac{dx}{(1-x)\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

but without using a trig substitution or integration by parts. I can already see that $x=\sin \theta$ works it out quite nicely, but I was hoping for an alternative solution. I tried usual suspects like $u=\frac{1}{x}$ but I didn't get very far with them. What could I perhaps try instead?

Comment: You take off two of the most useful, nice methods for **this** kind of integrals... perhaps there is some slick trick to this otherwise, but I think there's a good chance any other more or less elementary method will be pretty ugly.

Comment: This is an odd question. The obvious thing to try first is to differentiate $\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-x}$ because that would give you the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$. But actually that is the answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let
$$u=\frac{1}{1-x}$$

Then,
$$du=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}dx$$
and
$$u-ux=1$$
$$x=1-\frac1u$$
Thus,

$$\int \frac{dx}{(1-x)\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\int \frac{(1-x)dx}{(1-x)^2\sqrt{1-x^2}}\int\frac{du}{u\sqrt{(1-(1-\frac1u)^2)}}=\int\frac{du}{u\sqrt{(1-1-\frac1{u^2}+\frac2u)}}=\int\frac{du}{u\sqrt{(-\frac1{u^2}+\frac2u)}}=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{2u-1}}du$$

which can be easily solved.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach which does not make use of a trigonometric substitution.
\begin{align*}
\int \frac{dx}{(1 - x)\sqrt{1 - x^2}} &= \int \frac{dx}{(1 - x)\sqrt{(1 - x)(1 + x)}}\\
&= \int \frac{1}{(1 - x)\sqrt{(1 - x)(1 + x)}} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{1 - x}}{\sqrt{1 - x}} \, dx\\
&= \int \sqrt{\frac{1 - x}{1 + x}} \frac{dx}{(1 - x)^2}
\end{align*}
Now using the self-similar substitution of $u = \dfrac{1 - x}{1 + x}$, we see that $x = \dfrac{1 - u}{1 + u}$, giving $dx = -\dfrac{2}{(1 + u)^2} \, du$.

Noting that $1 - x = \dfrac{2u}{1 + u}$, the integral becomes
\begin{align*}
\int \frac{dx}{(1 - x)\sqrt{1 - x^2}} &= \int \sqrt{u} \cdot \left (\frac{1 + u}{2u} \right )^2 \cdot -\frac{2}{(1 + u)^2} \, dx\\
&= -\frac{1}{2} \int u^{-3/2} \, du\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}} + {\cal{C}}\\
&= \sqrt{\frac{1 + x}{1 - x}} + \cal{C}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

Let $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$. Then, $ydy =-xdx$

\begin{align}
&\int \frac{dx}{(1-x)\sqrt{1-x^2}}\\
= &\int \frac{dx}{(1-x)y}
= \int \frac{(y^2-x(1-x))dx}{(1-x)^2y}
=\int \frac{ydx+(1-x)dy}{(1-x)^2}\\=&\int d\left(\frac y{1-x} \right)=\frac y{1-x}+C=\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-x}+C
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Applying [Euler's Second Substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution#Euler%27s_second_substitution), $$\sqrt{1 - x^2} = t x - 1 ,$$ i.e., $$x = \frac{2 t}{1 + t^2}, \qquad dx = \frac{2 (1 - t^2)}{(1 + t^2)^2} \,dt ,$$
transforms the integral into
$$-2\int \frac{dt}{(t - 1)^2} = \frac{2}{t - 1} + C_0 = \boxed{\frac{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}{1 - x} + C} .$$